# Beagle Board Black Revision

Tags: beagleboard, beaglebone

I can't seem to find my revision number on my Beagle Board Black. Does anyone know where it is printed? Yes it's on the box, but that doesn't help down the road once the box is gone. Seems silly that they got (at least I think) silk screen the revision on the board. Others have suggested that its on a white sticker on the ethernet, but none of ours have this. It was not peeled off either. Never had it to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh, I found it... It was not on the ethernet, I completely missed the sticker on the riser.

Comment: Not all Revisions have that sticker. If you are running one of the default images and use your browser to navigate to the BeagleBone Black, then the green box that tells you BoneScript has connected, also tells you the revision number.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a serial console installed, you can also get the revision from the uBoot prompt.

1. When booting the device, enter the space key to stop at the uBoot prompt
2. Then issue the command

   `printenv board_rev`

This should diplay something like 

`board_rev=00C0`

where **C** is here my beagle board revision.